# Leaving out the article 'the' without change in meaning?

Tags: definite-article

Although I've read a few grammar books, sometimes I'm not sure if I should use 'the'.

These two phrasas are from the figure captions of a paper published in the journal *Physical Review B*:

> 1. Time dependence of electron temperature at the front and back surfaces of the target.
> 2. The temperature dependence of the volume of the copper material.

Is one of these incorrect grammatically/semantically?

Comment: Grammar rules for headlines, titles, and captions are different than for regular speech or writing.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax of things like titles and headlines is different from normal speech. One the distinctions is that articles are often omitted.

In most contexts "Time dependence of ... " would require an article, but in titles and captions it doesn't need one.

Comment: Could you please explain why "time dependence of ..." (without the definite article) is incorrect when used in a normal context?

Comment: @Arham, Research the [zero article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-marking_in_English#Zero_article). You would only omit the article if you're talking about the general idea of time dependence, rather than the time dependence of one particular thing.

Comment: @ThePhoton, what about 'drunken fans' in this example from _Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary_: 'The game was marred by the behaviour of drunken fans.'? These drunken fans were watching the game. So they form a specific group of people; but the definite article hasn't been used here.

Comment: That's an interesting example that doesn't fit the simplest rules for using the zero article. It could be worth asking a new question about.

Comment: You can't talk about "the drunken fans" unless the fans have already been introduced in context. So you might say "the game was marred by the behavior of *some* drunken fans". Often *some* can be omitted without changing meaning. The [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/quantifiers/some) website talks about strong and weak uses of *some*, and it seems to me that their examples of weak usage could all be omitted; but their section on "Leaving out *some*" doesn't say this explicitly. I don't know if this is British/American difference (I'm American).

Comment: @ThePhoton, It seems to me that the wikipedia text you suggested differentiates between 'generic plural noun' and 'indefinite plural noun'. Maybe the phrase 'drunken fans' in the above example is an instance of 'indefinite plural noun', which, according to the wikipedia text, can be used without any article.

Comment: When a new entity is introduced into the disourse, it is usually indefinite: _I saw a man enter_; _People were arriving_. Once the entity has been introduced, it is definite: _The man was tall_. _The people were wearing coats_. _In most contexts, the (indefinite) drunken fans would be expressed as _some drunken fans_. I think the use of _drunken fans_ without an article or _some_ is unusual in ordinary speech, and is a construction I particularly associate with journalism: it's not headlinese, because it can occur within a new story; but I don't think it would occur in many other places